# jQuery/javascript different behaviours with user click and programatically click a checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox, click, dom-events

A bit hard to explain, so I've set up a jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BCECy/).

Basically, I have some behaviour triggered when a user clicks a checkbox. In another place I'm trying to programatically click the check box and I need to see the exact same behaviour. It doesn't work, seemingly something to do with the order of the click and determining the checked attribute.

How can I get the behaviour I'm looking for without resorting to a hack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to use `change` handler here instead (since jQuery normalizes the behavior, it doesn't require a `blur`), then fire that event like this:

```
$('span').click(function() { $('.test').click().change(); });
```

Then, you're explicit about the order...and you don't have the issue of the native action vs event handler order, [you can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/BCECy/3/).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to put javascript for this behaviour... just use this html syntax :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="myid" />&nbsp;<label for="myid">My Label</label>
```

If you want to add javascript listners, you can add change or click to input field.

:)

OR you should do that using jquery :

```
$('span').click(function() { $('.test').trigger('click'); });
```

Comment: This works for the example, but not the general question, which was programmatic clicking of the checkbox :)

Comment: this line do the trick $('span').click(function() { $('.test').trigger('click'); });

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it calling the javascript click function instead of jQuery one like this:

```
$('.test')[0].click();
```